# Angular CLI - Do not show any error output when used 'ng serve'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I Build the angular project in **--prod --aot** mode I 
get this error :

> "Property 'X' is private and only accessible within class

**How can i set my app to show this error in 'ng serve' mode too?**

Comment: you can set your compiler to compile on AOT by "ng serve --aot true"

Comment: AFAIK `--aot` has not been necessary for a while. `--prod` enables it by default. Check the angular.json file for the enabled flags. That being said, we don't know what "X" is or what your class looks like, how it's being used, etc. Please post relevant code. `ng serve --prod` enables production mode (with AOT in recent versions).

Comment: Thanks @lpradhap , But I know there is an option to declare it using schematics in angular.json any idea how?

Comment: change in package.json/angular.json to `"start": "ng serve --aot"` then try `npm start`

Comment: if the property X is private and is accessible from the template then mark it as public property.

Comment: I put property 'x' as an example only. the question was how to declare  that this error and more will display on 'ng serve' just like in prod mode

Comment: @ashishpal's answer appears to be correct.  ashishpal can you provide your comment as an answer?